# Express the epigraph of a parabola as a set of linear inequalities

Tags: geometry

Consider the following problem, from the Book *Geometry* by Prasolov and Tikhomirov:

> Specify the following sets by systems of linear inequalities:
>   $x_2\ge x_1^2$ (the "epigraph" of a parabola).

I am puzzled. Since the parabola is a quadratic function, how can I express this set with linear inequalities?

Somehow this should be possible, because there is a subsequent exercise which asks to describe the following set:

$\{(x_1,x_2) | \; x_1x_2\ge 1,\; x_1\ge0, \; x_2\ge 0\}$

as a system of linear inequalities.

Comment: Consider it as the intersection of (the set of) epigraphs of all tangents.

Comment: But wouldn't this require infinitely many (uncountably many) equations? Something like: $x_1\ge 2x_2 + q$, $q\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Of course it requires an infinite system of inequalities (technically, "countably many" is sufficient here - if we take tangents at points of some dense countable subset of the boundary). It is not asked to find *finite* systems - and that cannot be done.

Comment: Ok, I see. I consider it a bit a misleading problem, but I guess that the authors just wanted to underline how linear inequalities can be used to approximate the description of nonlinear convex sets.